# Remove numbers which are repeated several times in a row

Tags: groovy

I have collection

```
def list = [4,1,1,1,3,5,1,1]
```

and I need to remove numbers which are repeated three times in a row. As a result I have to get an [4,3,5,1,1]. How to do this in groovy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by copying the list while ensuring the two previous elements are not the same as the one to be copied.  If they are, drop the two previous elements, otherwise copy as normal.

This can be implemented with [`inject`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#inject%28U,%20groovy.lang.Closure%29) like this:

```
def list = [4,1,1,1,3,5,1,1]
def result = list.drop(2).inject(list.take(2)) { result, element -> 
    def prefixSize = result.size() - 2
    if ([element] * 2 == result.drop(prefixSize)) { 
        result.take(prefixSize)
    } else {
        result + element
    }
}
assert result == [4,3,5,1,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the uniques size in the next three elements and drop them when they are 1:

```
def list = [4,1,1,1,3,5,1,1]
assert removeTriplets(list) == [4,3,5,1,1]

def removeTriplets(list) {
  listCopy = [] + list
  (list.size()-3).times { index ->
    uniques = list[index..(index+2)].unique false
    if (uniques.size() == 1) 
      listCopy = listCopy[0..(index-1)] + listCopy[(index+3)..-1]
  }
  listCopy
}
```

Comment: I believe you could use `list.collate( 3, 1 )` as well

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [Run Length Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)

First lets define a class which will hold our object and the number of times it occurs in a row:

```
class RleUnit {
  def object
  int runLength

  RleUnit( object ) {
    this( object, 1 )
  }

  RleUnit( object, int runLength ) {
    this.object = object
    this.runLength = runLength
  }

  RleUnit inc() {
    new RleUnit( object, runLength + 1 )
  }

  String toString() { "$object($runLength)" }
}
```

We can then define a method which will encode a List into a List of `RleUnit` objects:

```
List<RleUnit> rleEncode( List list ) {
  list.inject( [] ) { r, v ->
    if( r && r[ -1 ].object == v ) {
      r.take( r.size() - 1 ) << r[ -1 ].inc()
    }
    else {
      r << new RleUnit( v )
    }
  }
}
```

And a method that takes a List of `RleUnit` objects, and unpacks it back to the original list:

```
List rleDecode( List<RleUnit> rle ) {
  rle.inject( [] ) { r, v ->
    r.addAll( [ v.object ] * v.runLength )
    r
  }
}
```

We can then encode the original list:

```
def list = [ 4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 1, 1 ]
rle = rleEncode( list )
```

And filter this RleUnit list with the Groovy find method:

```
// remove all elements with a runLength of 3
noThrees = rle.findAll { it.runLength != 3 }
unpackNoThrees = rleDecode( noThrees )
assert unpackNoThrees == [ 4, 3, 5, 1, 1 ]

// remove all elements with a runLength of less than 3
threeOrMore = rle.findAll { it.runLength >= 3 }
unpackThreeOrMore = rleDecode( threeOrMore )
assert unpackThreeOrMore == [ 1, 1, 1 ]
```